# How can I open new tab in bootgrid link column?

Tags: php, html, jquery-bootgrid

I have used a bootgrid based database with links and is working fine. But my problem is that whenever I click the link it opens in the same window. How can I force the browser to open the link in a new tab?

I tried using the `target="_blank"` but it's not working. Here is the formatter:

```
formatters: {
            "link": function(column, row) {
                        return "<a href=\"download.php?FID="+row.fileID+"\"> Download </a>"
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works for me:

```
formatters: {
  "link": function(column, row) {
    return "<a target='_blank' href='download.php?FID=" + row.fileID + "'> Download </a>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working..Can you help me modify the following code also?

Comment: Please help me with this also.I have embedded the link inside a button and i want to open in new tab                                                      "download": function(column, row) 
   {
    return '<a href="downloadfile.php?fid='+row["fid"]+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-row-id="' + row.fid + '">Download</buttn></a> ';
   },

Comment: i can't help you if I don't see your whole code and table